# How would describe this editing technique

Tags: editing, vegas-pro

I am trying to write about the editing techniques in this clip here:

and at the 0:39-0:41 section I want to describe what editing technique is used where the scene stays the says but the character changes but I can't find any terms that describe it.

Thanks for any help.

(The film is what I made for college, it was not great as the camera we used was terrible and we ran into a lot of issues)

Comment: Those are usually called jump cuts, but I'm not completely sure in that situation where it cuts to multiple people doing the same action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a jump cut (creating a short video loop) followed by a [match cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Match_cut).